# Need to enable button WHEN Recaptcha and checkbox has been validated

Tags: jquery, django

I'm quite new to Django, jQuery so need some help here(basically a noob). I need enable **Start Test** button after the *recaptcha* has been validated from the server side,cannot be bypassed from front-end and *check box* has been checked. I did checkbox thing earlier but don't know how to add Captcha to that.

**HTML CODE**

```html
<div
  class="g-recaptcha captcha-button"
  align="center"
  data-sitekey="sitekey"
></div>
<br />
<div class="form-check test-check-button" align="center">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input display-7" id="instructions" />
  <label class="form-check-label text-center" for="instructions">
    <strong>I have read the instructions given above.</strong></label
  >
</div>
<div class="mb-5 mt-2 text-center start-button" id="startButton"></div>

<script>
  $("#instructions").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/test/confirm",
      data: {
        checkbox: 1,
      },
      dataType: "json",

      success: function (data) {
        if (data.button) {
          $(".test-check-button").html("");
          $(".start-button").html(data.button);
        }
      },
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Views.py**

```
def confirm(cls, request: HttpRequest):
        button = '<button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" id="submit_test" type="submit">Start 
           Test</button>'
        data = {'button': button}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

There's no forms.py in the project. So wanted to know how I can validate the captcha server-side without forms and enable the Start test button after validation and checkbox is checked. Thank you.

[Without start button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBhrG.png)

[With Start button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llKmq.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a data-callback attribute:

```js
function myCallback(){
  $('button').prop( "disabled", false )
}
```

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="myCallback"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The solution is still not working. I need validate captcha as well as checkbox. Only then the START TEST button will appear. Is there any way to do that ?